# HOW TO FIX: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR, expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php, syntax-error

This is the PHP code:

```
function my_profile_link() {

global $bp;



if ( $bp->loggedin_user->id )

echo ‘loggedin_user->domain . $bp->profile->slug . ‘/”>Profile‘;

}
```

I'm getting the error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR, expecting ',' or ';'" on the line:

> echo ‘loggedin_user->domain . $bp->profile->slug . ‘/”>Profile‘;

I didn't write this code (I don't know anything about PHP), I'm just using it.

Comment: If you don't know anything about PHP, then StackOverflow isn't really for you... You need to at least know the basics.

Comment: I'm a newbie programmer. Since this is a programming question...StackOverflow is the place for this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change >

```
echo ‘loggedin_user->domain . $bp->profile->slug . ‘/”>Profile‘;
```

to >

```
echo $loggedin_user->domain . $bp->profile->slug . '/">Profile';
```

Comment: +1 for your willingness to help a newbie.

Comment: @Phphelp, we were all newbies when we started ;-)

Comment: @Glavić yes, but i have noticed that people at stackoverflow are often rude to newbies and just vote them down without helping.. :)

Answer (score 4):

Those aren't normal quote characters.